# JS Как сделать подсчет значений velue в выбранных checkbox:checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

помогите пожалуйста кодом.
Как сделать автоматический подсчет значений value из `<input type="checkbox" checked>`?

Например:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked name="mytest" value="100">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="mytest" value="200">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="mytest" value="300">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="mytest" value="400">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="mytest" value="500">

<div id="resultVal"> 1500 </div>
```

Вот выбраны все checkbox получаем результат `1500`
А если добавляется еще один checkbox value=600, без перезагрузки страницы результат станет `2100`

Как сделать такой функционал?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Из правил сообщества https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getResult = () => {
let result = 0;
  
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each((index, input) => {
        if ($(input).is(':checked')) {
        result += parseInt(input.value)
    }
    });
  
  
  return result;
}

const updateResult = () => {
    const result = getResult();
  $('#resultVal').text(result);
}

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(() => {
    updateResult();
});


updateResult();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L2oag4jv/